# How can I make a class implement an interface .... (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

... when the class acutally does provide implementations for all abstract methods, but is not "formally" implementing the interface?

Lets say I have the following:

```
class AInterface {
    public:
        virtual void mem_func()=0;
        virtual ~AInterface(){}
};

void AFunction(AInterface* i){};

class BClass {
    public:
        void mem_func(){}
        virtual ~BClass(){}
};
```

and I cannot change any of this but I want to use an object of class BClass to call AFunction.

Actually, I would like to write something like

```
class MyABClass : public BClass,public AInterface {};
```

but this doesnt help (the class just inherits both methods and is abstract). I guess one way to do this is writing something like

```
class MyABClass : public AInterface {
    public:
        void mem_func(){a.mem_func();}
    private:
        BClass a;
}
```

This works fine, but I wonder if it is possible to save some writing or if there is some better way to deal with this situation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve or is this just general exploration of OOP in C++? It looks like you're trying to implement Mixins but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Why not just `class MyClass : public AClass {}`?

Comment: I don't think you can make it as you want. Suppose AInterface::A() isn't pure virtual, compiler can't know which one to call when you call MyClass::A(). If AInterface::A() is pure virutal function, compiler need to find A() first.

Comment: Make sure you understand what a virtual destructor is and when to use it.

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks for pointing it out, I am aware of this issue but I left it out. Actually, my intention was to make it more clear, but I think it really is better to put the destructor also in a snippet. I will edit it...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ AInterface is pure abstract (otherwise I would not call it "interface" :P). However, even if it wasnt, I dont really understand your comment. However, I will have to take a look and if I dont get it it would be a different question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Why not just class MyClass : public AClass {}" ... because then I still cannot call AFunction(&a) with an MyClass a, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @tobi303 _"or am I missing something here?"_ Obviously. This should work. Did you try it already?

Comment: @MorphingDragon Maybe with mixins, this situation can be handled more elegant, but my question was really about having AInterface, AFunction and AClass given (from somewhere) without being able to change any of them directly. Actually I was thinking to write a template that could take any class as parameter and implements the AInterface by simply forwarding the calls to the template parameter class calls. I guess this is going into the direction of mixins.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I already tried it, but just to be sure I did it again, and my compiler (VS) complains about : " AFunction: cannot convert parameter 1 from MyClass* to AInterface*". Maybe a simple conversion can help, but just like this it does not work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You've missed the point. `class MyClass : public AClass {}` cannot be passed as a `AInterface&`, so you've failed to meet the requirements there.

Comment: @MooingDuck Would it go well with a `static_cast<AInterface&>(myClass)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That would be undefined behavior, and since the vtables are unlikely to line up, member functions would probably fail to work in every existing implementation.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh sorry, facepalm! I didn't spot that `AClass` actually doesn't inherit/implement the `AInterface`. It seems I was distracted by the implementation of the `A()` class member function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Renamed classes and member functions, does it seem clearer now?  Also, I just learned that `using` won't override: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67d069cd58e81cf5

Comment: I think the correct answer is "No there is no better way than what you already have"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an approach quite similar to your last code snippet

```
class MyABClass : public AInterface {
    public:
        void MyABClass(BClass &_a)
            : a(_a)
        {}
        void mem_func(){a.mem_func();}
    private:
        BClass &a;
}
```

This is a design pattern and is called [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (with delegation). Maybe you also want to read about the [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) pattern.

**Update** (considering Kenny's comment): Whether you pass `BClass` as a reference or a copy is debatable. It depends on what you want. If you want a wrapper for conveniently altering the original `BClass` instance then use `BClass &` as constructor parameter. On the other hand if a copy is sufficient then use just `BClass` without ampersand `&`. Well, *if* a copy constructor is available. Finally you have to pay attention when using a reference that you may create side-effects (which, again, may be desired or not).

Comment: Yes, using a default constructed AClass object makes my snippet rather useless in some cases. And thanks for pointing out that this is a design pattern. I always feel better using some well established pattern instead of my own "somehow-I-made-it-work" solutions ;)

Comment: Bonus points for naming the design pattern, but don't use a reference. As your link shows, the proxy should own the private instance, or extend the class so that it is the instance (which makes it the other equivalent answer, multiple inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was almost right

```
class MyClass : public AClass,public AInterface {};
```

The problem is that MyClass does not know that AClass::A() satisfies the requirement posed by AInterface::A()=0. Give it a little help like so

```
class MyClass : public AClass, public AInterface {
    void A() {AClass::A();}
};
```

Comment: @tobi303 - your code with multiple inheritance was almost right. This corrects it in the one minor detail it was lacking.

Comment: after reading your posts and the previous edits, I know what you mean, but I think it is not clear to what code you are refering if someone reads my question and your answer.